While Migrating asp.net membership db tables to Asp.Net Core identity db tables throwing error
When upgrading asp.net membership to asp.net core identity. I have created identity tables.
while inserting membership table to identity table throwing error.
INSERT INTO AspNetUsers(Id,UserName,PasswordHash,Discriminator,SecurityStamp,
ApplicationId,LoweredUserName,MobileAlias,IsAnonymous,LastActivityDate,LegacyPasswordHash,
MobilePIN,Email,LoweredEmail,PasswordQuestion,PasswordAnswer,IsApproved,IsLockedOut,CreateDate,
LastLoginDate,LastPasswordChangedDate,LastLockoutDate,FailedPasswordAttemptCount,
FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart,FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount,FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart,Comment)
SELECT aspnet_Users.UserId,aspnet_Users.UserName,(aspnet_Membership.Password+'|'+CAST(aspnet_Membership.PasswordFormat as varchar)+'|'+aspnet_Membership.PasswordSalt),'User',NewID(),aspnet_Users.ApplicationId,aspnet_Users.LoweredUserName,
aspnet_Users.MobileAlias,aspnet_Users.IsAnonymous,aspnet_Users.LastActivityDate,aspnet_Membership.Password,
aspnet_Membership.MobilePIN,aspnet_Membership.Email,aspnet_Membership.LoweredEmail,aspnet_Membership.PasswordQuestion,aspnet_Membership.PasswordAnswer,
aspnet_Membership.IsApproved,aspnet_Membership.IsLockedOut,aspnet_Membership.CreateDate,aspnet_Membership.LastLoginDate,aspnet_Membership.LastPasswordChangedDate,
aspnet_Membership.LastLockoutDate,aspnet_Membership.FailedPasswordAttemptCount, aspnet_Membership.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart,
aspnet_Membership.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount,aspnet_Membership.FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart,aspnet_Membership.Comment
FROM aspnet_Users
LEFT OUTER JOIN aspnet_Membership ON aspnet_Membership.ApplicationId = aspnet_Users.ApplicationId
AND aspnet_Users.UserId = aspnet_Membership.UserId;
i am trying to  execute above query it will throwing error. Like "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IsApproved', table 'MH-OLC-Security.dbo.AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.".
and again i tried to given default value of isApproved "1". but again throwing error like "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IsLockedOut', table 'MH-OLC-Security.dbo.AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.".

Please can any one help me
